# Autocompleting console input

Tags: c#, console, autocomplete

Yesterday I stumbled upon a [Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39029847/1188513) that asked if it was possible to implement <kbd>Tab</kbd>-triggered auto-completion in a console application.

I thought that was an interesting idea, so I went ahead and wrote a small program that does just that, given a hard-coded `string[]` - I might eventually refactor it into its own class and reuse it in my own projects if I ever actually need auto-completion in a console app, but before I do that I'd like some feedback on the way it's implemented, given `static` aside, the logic itself is pretty much the way I'll have it regardless of whether it's in a dedicated class as part of something much bigger, or right there in a console application that does nothing but verify that the code works.

Pressing <kbd>Tab</kbd> when there's no input will change the current line to say `Bar`; because there's a word in `data` that starts with `Bar`, pressing <kbd>Tab</kbd> again will autocomplete to `Barbec`; another <kbd>Tab</kbd> will make it `Barbecue`, and then any subsequent <kbd>Tab</kbd> will have no effect, because nothing in the `data` starts with `Barbecue` - but then you could <kbd>Backspace</kbd> until the input is `Ba`, type a <kbd>t</kbd> to make it `Bat`, and when you press <kbd>Tab</kbd> then it autocompletes to `Batman`.

In other words, it all works exactly as it should. But does it *look* right?

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var data = new[]
        {
            "Bar",
            "Barbec",
            "Barbecue",
            "Batman",
        };

        var builder = new StringBuilder();
        var input = Console.ReadKey(intercept:true);

        while (input.Key != ConsoleKey.Enter)
        {
            if (input.Key == ConsoleKey.Tab)
            {
                HandleTabInput(builder, data);
            }
            else
            {
                HandleKeyInput(builder, data, input);
            }

            input = Console.ReadKey(intercept:true);
        }
        Console.Write(input.KeyChar);
    }

    /// <remarks>
    /// https://stackoverflow.com/a/8946847/1188513
    /// </remarks>>
    private static void ClearCurrentLine()
    {
        var currentLine = Console.CursorTop;
        Console.SetCursorPosition(0, Console.CursorTop);
        Console.Write(new string(' ', Console.WindowWidth));
        Console.SetCursorPosition(0, currentLine);
    }

    private static void HandleTabInput(StringBuilder builder, IEnumerable<string> data)
    {
        var currentInput = builder.ToString();
        var match = data.FirstOrDefault(item => item != currentInput && item.StartsWith(currentInput, true, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(match))
        {
            return;
        }

        ClearCurrentLine();
        builder.Clear();

        Console.Write(match);
        builder.Append(match);
    }

    private static void HandleKeyInput(StringBuilder builder, IEnumerable<string> data, ConsoleKeyInfo input)
    {
        var currentInput = builder.ToString();
        if (input.Key == ConsoleKey.Backspace && currentInput.Length > 0)
        {
            builder.Remove(builder.Length - 1, 1);
            ClearCurrentLine();

            currentInput = currentInput.Remove(currentInput.Length - 1);
            Console.Write(currentInput);
        }
        else
        {
            var key = input.KeyChar;
            builder.Append(key);
            Console.Write(key);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: very interesting question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Testing

- Personally I think it’s conceptually easier to test this code if you are returning a string – rather than a void: what if you decided to change the out put device from a console window to your printer – it would not be easy to change that. What if sometimes you wanted a console window and other times you wanted to send the same thing via text message? I guess it’s easier to separate what is being done vs how it is being done. E.g. Output key is the abstract concept but this could be done a number of different ways: (i) to the console, or (ii) through a voice synthesiser etc. I wrote some tests but then i threw it once it broke when i changed the API.

#### Naming

- What is `data`? It’s harder to think of a more abstract name. I’ve changed this to `keywords`.
- Personally I like to see the type along with the variable declaration.

#### Refactoring the code:

- I simplified and extracted some methods.
- The The HandleKeyInput and the HandleTabInput both seem to be doing conceptually similar things: a key is inputted and then a result is obtained. If it’s a tab then do X, but if it’s a key then do Y. There’s a common abstraction here that can be extracted.
- What I want to do is to make the two methods: HandleTabInput and HandleKeyInput to look and be absolutely identical.
- Data (renamed to keywords) can be a field so there’s no need to pass it in as a variable.
- I want to make two of your methods to basically be the same. They’re kinda doing this same things. After some refactoring this is what I got:

  ```
    public void HandleTabInput(StringBuilder builder, ConsoleKeyInfo keyInput)
    {
            // Perform calculation
        string match = ExtractMatch(builder);

            // Alter the builder
        builder.Clear();
        builder.Append(match);

            // Print Results
        PrintMatch(match);
    }
  ```

And then this:

```
    private void HandleKeyInput(StringBuilder builder, ConsoleKeyInfo keyInput)
    {
        if (keyInput.Key == ConsoleKey.Backspace && builder.ToString().Length > 0)
        {
                // Perform Calculation (nothing here)

                // Alter the builder
            builder.Remove(builder.Length - 1, 1);

                // Print Results
            ClearCurrentLine();                
            Console.Write(builder.ToString().Remove(builder.ToString().Length - 1));
        }
        else
        {
                // Perform calculation (nothing here)

                // Alter the Builder
            var key = keyInput.KeyChar;
            builder.Append(key);

                // Print Reuslts
            Console.Write(key);
        }
    }
```

We can abstract out the calculation, and then the printing. After some work this was the result. It’s starting to look pretty similar:

```
    private void HandleKeyInput(StringBuilder builder, ConsoleKeyInfo keyInput)
    {
        if (keyInput.Key == ConsoleKey.Backspace && builder.ToString().Length > 0)
        {
            Program.KeyInput backSpaceKey = new Program.KeyInput.BackspaceInput(builder, keywords);
            backSpaceKey.AlterBuilder();
            backSpaceKey.PrintResult();                
        }
        else
        {
            KeyInput input = new KeyInput.StandardKeyInput(builder, keywords, keyInput.KeyChar);
            input.AlterBuilder();
            input.PrintResult();
        }
    }
```

You could probably tidy things up a little more.

#### The final Result:

```
    public void RunProgram()
    {
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        ConsoleKeyInfo capturedCharacter = Console.ReadKey(intercept: true);

        while (EnterIsNotThe(capturedCharacter))
        {
            KeyInput key = KeyInput.GetKey(builder, keywords, capturedCharacter);
            builder = key.UpdateBuilder();
            key.Print();

            capturedCharacter = Console.ReadKey(intercept: true);
        }

        Console.Write(capturedCharacter.KeyChar);
    }
```

#### Concluding Thoughts

- It reads marginally better. Still If you want to reuse the code you’ll have to make changes, but at least it will be a little easier to do when the time comes.
- Encapsulation could be a little better – typically speaking you want the KeyInput class to be instantiated via the factory only.

[A link to see the full code.](https://gist.github.com/benkoshy/7f6f28e158032534615773a9a1f73a10)

Comment: I disagree on your concluding thoughts. If I understand them and the theory behind, in this practical case your code is harder to read read than his. The simpler the better.

Comment: @Alexis Pautrot - appreciate your comment. Chrs